# dynamic children in a react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am rendering components on a page from a JSON dataset - something like

```
[
  {
    "name": "compA",
    "label": "CompA Label"
  },
  {
    "name": "compB",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "compC"
      }
    ]
  }
]


renderElements = elements => {
  elements.map(element => {
    // get component based on name
    let Component = getComponentByName(element.name);
    return (
      <Component>
        {element.children && renderElements(elements.children)}
      </Component>
    );
  });
};
```

I have a code similar to above pseudocode that renders components dynamically based on the JSON dataset. However, in some cases, the JSON dataset gets loaded multiple times on the page and there are scenarios when one of the names in the second/third dataset matches the name in the first dataset, in which case, I need to re-use the component already rendered from first dataset and merge/inject the children dynamically into the already rendered component.

What would be the best way to do this?

1. Merge the datasets in the reducer and always render just the merged dataset? conceptually this sounds better but due to certain other complexities, this doesn't seem to work for me, so I am looking for alternatives.
2. Keep a ref to components somewhere and somehow call addChildren() or something similar if same name is found?
3. something else?

It's almost like a I need a singleton component instance that should be re-used if already rendered. but since that approach is frowned upon, I am trying to find the right way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most expensive part of repeated rendering is in the DOM, which React has covered with the shadow DOM. I wouldn't worry about it, because unless your rendering code does a lot of work, it is cheap compared to DOM operations

Comment: Use [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)